# Why are users disabled in the Build Permissions list and how can I enable them for distribution of my TestFlight app?

Tags: testflight

When I get ready to send out my IPA through TestFlight, I reach the Build Permissions list as expected.  This is the screen that has usernames for you to choose for distribution.

[image]

Some of those names are grayed out and I cannot select them.  I'm pretty sure they're in my provisioning profile and that I've uploaded their UDID.

How do I enable them?

Edit: alternately, I've heard that it's possible to superimpose a provisioning profile/distribution list after an app has been distributed.  Since I just want to get my app out to my testers ASAP, is that an option here for sending the app to the disabled folks?  Would *everyone* get spammed a second time, in that case?

Comment: Having the same issue here, no idea what is happening. Using the web interface I can distribute it to everyone.

Comment: Same issue here.  Did this ever start working for anyone?

Comment: Nope, never worked for me. I have a workaround if you're familiar with Provisioning Profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your provisioning profile has a list of devices associated with it. TestFlight grays out team members who don't have a device that's part of that list. This means, in the iOS Dev Center, you need to update your provisioning profile's list of devices (just check that entry) or even add the device to your dev account's master device list if needed.

Also, super-imposing a provisioning profile via TestFlight has never worked for me to update the original device list in the profile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This will, in fact, work if you've set up everything on TestFlight for that user and have them added to the provisioning profiles as mentioned. The workaround for this (contrary to the answer) is that super-imposing a provisioning profile via TestFlight's website has *always* worked for me, and continues to do so today.